# Can Gmapping package in ROS can create map at Runtime

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have gmapping package in ROS
Can we create a map in ROS at runtime using gmapping package and without using rosbag file ?
If yes ,then how it can be done ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241696/can-gmapping-package-in-ros-can-create-map-at-runtime/) by [Atul Divekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27747/atul-divekar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes this can be done.

Just set up `gmapping` as you do with the bagfile, but use the inputs of the real robot instead of the topics coming from the bagfile (i.e. the laserscanner message and the tf)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Atul Divekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27747/atul-divekar/) on 2016-08-16**:
If yes. Can you explained How it can be done with example?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-08-18**:
Check out the various packages configuring `gmapping`, e.g. [cob_mapping_slam](http://wiki.ros.org/cob_navigation)